# Calculate the size of a specific portion on a background set with background-size: cover;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-images

I am trying to build an hybrid app and I need to get the size of a specific porition of the background.

- The background has those properties : 

  `background-size: 100% 100%;
  background: url('back.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;`
- I would like to place a div over that background and set the size of the div to the size of a precise portion of the background.

Here is an image to clarify what I would like to do :
[Background example with a red rectangle on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBNx5.png)

The red rectangle on the backgroud image above is an example of the portion of the image I would like to calculate the size on a responsive screen.

I know how to make the elements follow the right absolute position on the background thanks to this topic [Position element over background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836753/position-element-over-background-image-but-the-bg-img-changes-size-with-the-win), but not how to resize them to the right scale.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Just to clarify; does that image have the red square on it and you want to place a div over the red square? Or, is that red square just a representation of how it should look (i.e. there is no red square on the actual image)?

Comment: The red square is on the image and I have to put a div exactly on the same place to replace the red scare by something in my div (ex: a photo), but the div has to have the same size as the red square (responsivly speaking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the problem, which was not as complicated as I thought.

- The first thing is to know the background width and height
- The second is to know the size of the element we want on the background (for exemple the red scare)

  ```
  // In css : background-size: 100% 100%;
  var background = {width: 1200, height: 900 };
  var redScare = {selector: '.redScare', width: 400, height: 342, x: 50, y: 60};

  var xFactor = $( window ).width() / background.width;
  var yFactor = $( window ).height() / background.height;


  // New width proportionally to the window size
  redScare.width = redScare.width * xFactor;
  // New height proportionally to the window size
  redScare.height = redScare.height * yFactor; 

  //Setting the new dimensions

  $(redScare.selector).css('width', redScare.width);
  $(redScare.selector).css('height', redScare.height);
  ```